# Call to a member function first() on double

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I got an error in

> Call to a member function first() on double

this is query builder in laravel

```
$player = DB::table('players')
                 ->join('stats', 'players.username', '=', 'stats.player')
                 ->sum('stats.winpot');
                 ->first();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

of course. it's obvious. the `sum()` function return sum of the selected column. a single value (not a collection of values)

the `first()` is for Collections, to get the first element from a collection.

Since the sum function returns the sum of the column values (A single value, not a Collection), you cant call `first()` function on it.

And Most importantly **You Don't Have To**.

**NOTE**

If you want to get **both** 'player' and the 'sum' you can execute two queries and bind those two results together.

Possible solution.

```
$player = DB::table('players')
                 ->join('stats', 'players.username', '=', 'stats.player')
                 ->first();

$player->sum = DB::table('players')
                     ->join('stats', 'players.username', '=', 'stats.player')
                     ->sum('stats.winpot');
```

now there is an attribute in retrieved 'player' as 'sum'. you can access it as `$player->sum`

Comment: so can you give me an example sum with first

Comment: just to be clear, do you want both the 'player' and the 'sum' ? because I thought you only needed the 'sum'.

Comment: well I did some research to get both the rows and the sum in a single query. but couldn't find any. but there is a way you could achieve that with two queries. If that would be ok with you, I will update the answer.

Comment: i got error like this Call to undefined method stdClass::setAttribute()